# Traveling by sea from India to Indonesia

Tags: india, international-travel, indonesia, sea-travel

Is it possible to travel by sea from India to Indonesia. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Might be possible by freighter? (Which is never cheap.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by container ship/freighter*.

There are many sites that offer exactly this service, either as booking agents or the line itself.  Here are some examples:

[Cargo Ship Voyages](http://cargoshipvoyages.com/)

[seaplus.com](http://www.seaplus.com/mainmenu.php)

[Freighter Cruises](https://www.freightercruises.com/voyages.php#anchor_menue)

However, India to Indonesia appears to have very infrequent or no scheduled service so you may have to research many options or combinations to find a routing that suits you.

*Of course, you can also charter a vessel.

Comment: *of* the line / *or* the line?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Unfortunately, none of the container ships allows embarkation/disembarkation in India...